# Some Javascript functions don't work on WAMP

Tags: javascript, php, html, wamp, wampserver

I wrote a javascript function that changes the background image of an element depending on which button is clicked. All images are stored in a separate folder. It works properly off of localhost but when i run the page on localhost, that particular function no longer works, all the other javascript functions work properly. I haven't implemented php yet on that page so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```js
function changeBG(btnID){
    var card = document.getElementById('edit');
    if(btnID == 'btn1')
        card.style.backgroundImage = "url('/images/1.JPG')";
    else if(btnID == 'btn2')
        card.style.backgroundImage = "url('/images/2.jpg')";
    else if(btnID == 'btn3')
        card.style.backgroundImage = "url('/images/3.jpg')";
    else if(btnID == 'btn4')
        card.style.backgroundImage = "url('/images/4.jpg')";
}
```

```css
.cardImage{
    height: 15rem;
    width: 30rem;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #a4bac0;
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardImage" id="edit">
    <h5>Card</h5>
</div>
<div class="options">
    <h6>Options</h6>
    <button class="op" id="btn1" onclick="changeBG(this.id);">1</button>
    <button class="op" id="btn2"  onclick="changeBG(this.id);">2</button>
    <button class="op" id="btn3"  onclick="changeBG(this.id);">3</button>
    <button class="op" id="btn4"  onclick="changeBG(this.id);">4</button>
    <button class="op" id="save">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine. Probably an issue with the image paths? Or that you aren't rendering it as a file that renders JavaScript?

Comment: there is necessarily an error message somewhere, either on the console or on your wamp server

Comment: PS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: @MisterJojo I'm not sure why I didn't sure switch from the beginning lol! Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, for some reason live changes to css don't show up on localhost unless you hard refresh a page! so I edited the javascript to refresh the div when an option is selected. Like below if anyones curious. Thanks for the suggestions :)

```
$("card").load("customize.php");
```